# Array in javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays

I have a label with text **"09-45"**. How do I get the texts **09** and **45** in 2 separate labels? I need this in a javascript function.

Comment: use split function to separate them.

Comment: Hi I am new to this. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: i posted answer below.

Comment: I get the result in Chrome..Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example:

```
var str = "09-45";
var spl = str.split("-");
var first = spl[0];
var second = spl[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `.split`?

```
var string = "string-split";
var arrayPieces = string.split('-');
alert(arrayPieces[1]); // Output: split
```

Comment: It shows this error in IE.."Line: 55
Error: Function expected"

Comment: I get the result in Chrome..Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `a = myvar.split("-");` to split the string to an array of strings.
Then `a[0]` will contain "09" and `a[1]` will contain "45";

Comment: It shows this error in IE.."Line: 55
Error: Function expected"

Comment: @Aishvarya: And what do you expect us to do with this information? We don't know your code.

Comment: @Felix: I wanted a general syntax that's it. Many people who have replied here don't know the code either.. anyway .. I have got the result in Chrome..Thanks.

Comment: @Aki: I get the result in Chrome..Thanks!